# Empty the internal DCIM Folder - Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera, storage

Hy, 
I want to empty the internal Folder "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera"
This works for me with the following code

```
public void emptyDir()
    {
        File dir = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera");
        if (dir.isDirectory())
        {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            {
                new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                Log.i(logTag,"Path " +dir +" cleared");
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I access/read this path without hardcode it?

The code to Capture my Picture:
I think most of the code is pretty clear what i meant to do because i always try to comment anything I do even if I'm just testing something new. I hope that I can show what i created with this one.

```
public void takePhoto()
{
    //Set the size of the Picture
    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setPictureSize(640, 480);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    //Befehl um die möglichen Auflösungen auszuwählen/aufzulisten
    //List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    //Take the Picture
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

    //SLEEP "sleeper value" SECONDS HERE ...
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            releaseCamera();
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.removeAllViews();
            activateCamera();
        }
    }, sleeper);
}

/**
 * Creates and Instance of Camera and adds CameraView to
 * camera_preview FrameLayout
 */
public void activateCamera()
{
    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}



final PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback()
{

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        if (pictureFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);

            fos.close();
            path = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Picture stored at: "+path);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), pictureFile.getName(), pictureFile.getName());
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
    }
};


/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try
    {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Camera in use");
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseCamera()
{
    if (mCamera != null)
    {
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private  File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
{
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    //File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MFI Webcam");

    File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath() + "/MFI Webcam");

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
    {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "webcam"+ ".jpg");
    } else
    {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DCIM)` you would probably get `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM`. But it is never a guarantee that the pictures will be there. They could as well be in `/storage/emulated/1/DCIM`. So better let the user indicate the right directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was exactly what i was searching for.
I'm pretty sure that the picture will always be there because i created an application that allowes me to handle the camera and uploads the taken picture for me then, the problem was that I couldn't find a way to delete the picture on the phone after the upload because saving it with the same name doesn't overwrite it

Comment: I thought that too but if I store my picture with the same name I just got two files (or more) - named webcam.jpg in my case, in the same folder
if the overwriting would work i would not even need to delete the folder..

Comment: Two files with the same name in one folder is not possible. How did you check?

Comment: Most interesting btw, I got a Dropbox Sync on my Phone and the Picture that gets Uploaded got another name than the Picture stored on the Phone, im not pretty sure how i did this :/

Comment: I checked that with File Explorer watching the properties from each file, i had about 50 pictures named webcam.jpg in that folder

Comment: Dropbox changes the filename of all pictures to be only a date format. It will remove for instance IMG_ from the name. But what has this to do with the impossibility of two equal filenames in one folder?

Comment: I have no idea how i can have more than files with the same name in that folder but it seems that i made it possible..
Btw thanks for that with dropbox, i didn't know that too..

Comment: I would like you to write a small functions that could create so much files in a folder with the same name.

Comment: I added anything that i used to take the picture for you at the code above, i can create a little empty application for you that creates multiple files with the same name if you still dont believe me. 
In my Application im taking the Picture with takePhoto(); at the end. Hope you saw what u wanted to see ;)
Edit: There may be some code that noone needs for this too i didn't check everything i copied out now^^

Comment: Could not wait till the weekend was over... I did not implement your code but after having looked at it better i saw nothing special in it. You just determine a filepath that ends with webcam.jpg and then open a FileOutputStream. I changed a take picture app of mine to not generate a different filename (with timestamp) but to keep one name (webcam.jpg ha ha). As expected it got overwritten. So yes i'm interested in a minimal code sample that could produce files with the same name. Or a demo apk with source.

Comment: i'll create an apk for you that takes the photo to show you the storage, is there a way i can send it to you via stackoverflow?

Comment: No. Not that i know of. Please place it somewher on the internet. A dropbox link would do.

Comment: I googled that problem and found a discussion about the same problem
http://superuser.com/questions/640419/how-can-i-have-two-files-with-the-same-name-in-a-directory-when-mounted-with-nfs
They say that they solved it and it's kinda bug or sth if i understood that right

Comment: On which Android version do you have this problem? Or on which device?

Comment: Galaxy S4 Mini - Android 4.2.2
Btw, I don't see it is a problem anymore since the Folder with the pictures gets emptied every day at 9pm now it's just a crazy bug now^^

Comment: Still you have a different bug. In the article only two with the same name and among many others. What i understood from you is that you just cann fill an empty dir with ten files with equal name. NFS? I don't know if that is used under Android. Android uses many file systems. On a removable sdcard it will be FAT. But internal is different. So you could investigste if the bug is there using internal, external or removable memory. And try on other devices.

Comment: it happens on internal storage, only on my s4 mini, htc legend and galaxy xcover it gets replaced

Comment: Ok. discussion closed.